# Using segmantic image segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I tried using the following example for an image I have. You can find the link [here](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Image_pascal.html). To reproduce the results I am getting consider the following image

[image]

When I apply the following code

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.semantic import semantic_segmentation

segment_image = semantic_segmentation()
segment_image.load_pascalvoc_model("deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
segment_image.segmentAsPascalvoc("125.jpg", output_image_name = "output.jpg")
```

I just get a black image. What I want is to segment the packages in the belt.

Comment: "*I just get a black image*", maybe it is labeled, please try to `print(numpy.unique(output))` to see the values inside the array, if they are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` they might not be visible but the output is labelled anyway!

Comment: @Bilal I have no idea what you mean by `output`, there is no output object in the code above.

Comment: "*output.jpg"*"

Comment: @Bilal It is just all zeros'

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason is obvious. pixellib cannot find any salient object to segment out and treating everything as background. This is because it is not trained to perform segmentation on such objects.

Considering that the packages that you are trying to detect are blurred and the rest of the image is just background it is treating the whole image as a background.

Now the solution will be to train your own image segmentation model or using image processing techniques such as blob detection (I have not tried this) or connected component analysis (there are implementation is well-known libraries such as skimage or OpenCV).